# Keyword const in class declarations

Tags: c++

I understand that the keyword const marks variables, parameters etc as read only. In a class declaration why is const used at the end of a member declaration, for example:

```
QString getClassName() const;
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a method `const` means that the method won't change the state of the object and thus it can be called on `const` instances of the class.

Notice that `const`-ness is enforced by the compiler. `const` methods can't modify member variables unless they are declared `mutable`. It's very common to have `mutable` locks so that `const` methods can still be synchronized.

Comment: You should also include the exception of mutable variables in your answer. It is an important aspect of const member-functions imo.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for the explanation. I never thought that far ahead with regards to const instances of the class.

Comment: @midor Added a note about that. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

It basically means that the function is "promising" that it won't change the calling object.

Comment: That's not just a "promise" though, a `const` method can't in fact change the instance state, i.e., the compiler will barf if you try (unless the variable you are trying to modify is marked as `mutable`).

Comment: I understand, I just couldn't think of a better word at that moment.

Comment: And of course you can always cast away the const-ness of the `this` pointer, though mutable is the appropriate way to achieve this.